# Where to place application logic in a Thruway app?

Tags: php, websocket, thruway

I build an app with Thruway and Autobahn.js This is the first time I use these tech, and I am a little lost with Thruway code. I read in a stackoverflow thread that :

“All application specific code should reside in WAMP application components, not in the router itself.”

But put these specific code where, how ?

For example, if a client subscribe to a chatroom, and the app need to log some thing, write in DB, manage sessions, (usual things)...
In facts, for each of type of message hello, error, subscribe, publish, etc...

If any of you have any code, it will be great. For me and for others dev, as I found no example in the ex. directory of Thruway.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about Thruway specifically, but generally: you can run WAMP components however you like. Any application written in a language for which a WAMP client library exists can be a WAMP component and connect to a WAMP router (like to Thruway, Crossbar.io etc.). There is no special mechanism for running them.

Comment: Thanks. I spoke to a Thruway dev. He gave me a lot of very good advices.

Comment: Well it would be nice if you could share those `good advises`

Comment: I bangs me when people brag about getting some information but they don't share it. I know years have passed since the comment but, author should provide this info for the community.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement internal client\clients and assign it directly to the router instance.

```
$router->addInternalClient(new InternalClient());
```

More info here http://voryx.net/creating-internal-client-thruway/